# How to make an android app from a website with php backend

Tags: php, android

there is login for my website.

3 pages which are used while logging into website are :-

1) login_form.html ( this html page has form in which users can fill data when they click submit it sends to login_validate.php)

2) login_validate.php ( this php page validates the input texts and if he is an authentic user  it redirects them to home.php)

3) home.php

I want to make an android login page,when correct login username and password are entered instead of showing home.php it should show some other thing.

I am able to make a POST http request to login_validate.php ,and i am getting home.php as reply,

my problem is how can i know that login is successful as i am not getting any reply as success or failure.i am getting login_form.html when authentication is wrong and home.php when username and password are right....

in my android app how can i know whether he entered right username and password or not correct credentials from the data i got from the server now???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In login_validate.php return only 'Ok' or 'Bad' status. And then redirect manualy to any page you need.

Answer (score 0):

---

Use Http Response to take a response from the php script you are posting your data to. It can echo a 0 or 1 depending on whether the authentication is successful. Now read the response in your app and redirect.

```
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                String getURL = "http://www.example.in";
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                if (resEntityGet != null) 
                {  
                            //do something with the response
                            Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                        }
```